# Trying to get all links from string which ends with ','

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I need to get all links with albums of artist from Genius page. All links can be found in fifth *tag* **preload-content** value of *attribute* **data-preload_data**. This value store in var string as str.

I tried to extract all links start with 'https://genius.com/albums/' and end with ',' but it didn't work. When i didn't use $ sign for ending i got right amount of links but without necessary ending part

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ssl
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import re

name = input('Rapper - ')
url = 'https://genius.com/artists/'+name+''
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
req = Request(url,headers=hdr)
html = urlopen(req)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

hrefs = soup.find_all("preload-content")
string = hrefs[5]['data-preload_data']

result = re.findall('(https://genius.com/albums/'+name+'.,$)', string)
print(result)
```

Comment: Still no matches

Comment: Can you provide the start url where _All links can be found in fifth tag preload-content value of attribute data-preload_data._ ?

Comment: I think you want something like `re.findall(r'https://genius\.com/albums/\S*,',string)` or `re.findall(r'''https://genius.com/albums/[^"'\s<>]*,''',text)`, see [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/2hmxwT).

Comment: @QHarr it is var url. 
For example - https://genius.com/artists/Aesop-rock

Comment: @WiktorStribiżewre ```findall(r'https://genius\.com/albums/\S*,',string)``` it returned almost full value of attribute and didn't stop at the end of link

Comment: but where are you extracting links from? Which page? The Aesop rock url has no [data-preload_data] attribute

Comment: I have just tried with `name='Face'` and got `string` equal to `'{"artist_has_more_songs":true}'`. Are you sure you scrape the right elements in the HTML?

Comment: Well, after checking the HTML, I think `re.findall(r'(https://genius\.com/albums/' + name + '/[^"\'\s<>]*?)&quot;,', string)` should work. Check [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yEWVYL/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Greatly appreciate your help. Спасибо за Фейса :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
re.findall(r'(https://genius\.com/albums/' + re.escape(name) + '/[^"\'\s<>]*?)&quot;,', string)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yEWVYL/1).

**Details**

- `(https://genius\.com/albums/' + re.escape(name) + '/[^"\'\s<>]*?)` - Group 1:

  - `https://genius\.com/albums/' + re.escape(name) + '/`  - a literal substring
  - `[^"\'\s<>]*?` - any zero or more chars other than `"`, `'`,  whitespace, `<` and `>`, as *few as possible* (due to `*?` lazy quantifier)
- `&quot;,` - a literal string

Note the `name` when used in a regex must have all special chars escaped for the regex to be syntactically correct, hence the use of `re.escape(name)`.